# How to display Json multiple data in html Nativescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have this JSON, I need to display all data like below:

```
res {
   "StatusCode": 0,
   "StatusMessage": "OK",
   "StatusDescription": [
     {
       "sensors": [
         {
           "serial": "sensor1",
           "id": "1"
         },
         {
           "serial": "sensor2",
           "id": "2"
         },
         {
           "serial": "sensor3",
           "id": "3"
         }
       ],
       "HBP_id": "12",
       "HB_id": "123",
      "serial_number": "hb1",
      "note": "test"
    },
               {
       "sensors": [
         {
           "serial": "sensor4",
           "id": "4"
         },
         {
           "serial": "sensor5",
           "id": "5"
         },
         {
           "serial": "sensor6",
           "id": "6"
         }
       ],
       "HBP_id": "23",
       "HB_id": "234",
      "serial_number": "hb2",
      "note": "test"
    },
               {
       "sensors": [
         {
           "serial": "sensor7",
           "id": "7"
         },
         {
           "serial": "sensor8",
           "id": "8"
         }
       ],
       "HBP_id": "34",
       "HB_id": "345",
      "serial_number": "hb3",
      "note": "test"
    }
   ]
 }
```

I want to display in html Nativescript these data:

### Product 1:

Serial: 
hb1

Sensors: 
sensor1
sensor2
sensor3

Serial: 
hb2

Sensors: 
sensor3
sensor4
sensor5

Serial: 
hb3

Sensors: 
sensor7
sensor8

I tried this code, but with this I can show only for first data:

```
<ListView [items]="items" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
                    <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
                        <StackLayout [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even">
                            <Label [text]="item.serial_number"></Label>
                            <Label *ngFor="let subItem of item?.sensors" [text]="subItem.serial"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ng-template>
                </ListView>
```

component.ts:

```
public items: Items[];
constructor(private service: ItemsService) {
}
public ngOnInit() {
    this.getallitems();
}

getallitems() {
    this.service.itemsGetAll().subscribe(
        items=> {
            console.log('itemsfrom ws',items) // show all 
            this.items= items;
        }
    );
}
```

service.ts

```
public itemsGetAll(): Observable<Items[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.itemsGetAll), {
        headers: headers
    })
        .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
            console.log('response', response)
            let res = response.json();
            if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
            } else {
                return res.StatusDescription.map(hbp => {
                    return hbp;
                });
            }
        }))
}
```

Display:

Serial: 
hb1

Sensors: 
sensor1
sensor2
sensor3

Can you ask me, how to use *ngFor in items? Any idea please?

Update:
I change my html like this:

```
   <StackLayout [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even">
          <Label *ngFor="let item of items" [text]='"[" + item.serial_number +"] " + item?.sensors'></Label> 
   </StackLayout>
```

[image: Show]

Comment: Can you share the exact `items` array? The JSON you have shared is not an array, maybe you extract `StatusDescription` but it'd be better if you make it clear.

Comment: I edit my post, with ts code

Comment: I asked for the content of the `items` array rather then code or the process to generate it. Get and share it as you did for the JSON object in you first block in the question body!

Comment: Can you write any example please, I don't understand very well. Thnx

Comment: The `items` you print to your ows console as you do at `console.log('itemsfrom ws',items) // show all` line.

Comment: Yes,the data are received from `console.log('itemsfrom ws',items)` and I want to show in html these data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173953/discussion-between-vahdet-and-site).

Answer (score 0):

You should be change to this :

```
<ListView [items]="items?.StatusDescription" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
  //Your code here
</ListView>
```

Rest of code will be same !!!

Comment: @site use this  `this.service.itemsGetAll()..subscribe((items: any)=> { this.items= items.StatusDescription;});` and rest of code will be same

Comment: If I used like there, items are undefined.`console.log('itemsfrom ws',items)` show all data correctly. I think that the problem is in html code. In ts for my opinion it's ok

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

```
public items: Items[];
constructor(private service: ItemsService) {
}
public ngOnInit() {
    this.getallitems();
}

getallitems() {
    this.service.itemsGetAll().subscribe(
        items=> {
            console.log('itemsfrom ws',items) // show all 
            this.items= items.StatusDescription;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: If I used like there, items are undefined.console.log('itemsfrom ws',items) show all data correctly. I edit my service code. I think that the problem is in html, in ts code all data arrive correctly

Comment: It's working fine plz check link https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=YpB3BI&v=2

Comment: I see in your code that you have NativeScriptUI.I do not have them. Are important?